Google Slides, how to programmatically create a numbered list and modify the starting index
I'm currently trying to automate the creation of a Google Slides based on data from Sheets. The idea is to give each data row from the Sheet its own Slide (works just fine so far) and include a table of contents. The problem arises here though. I map out my data array to a string version of it then display it as a numbered list on the slide.
However, getting it to be properly displayed becomes an issue. Since it's possible to be dealing with 10+ items and I want some proper spacing between each, a single column will overflow outside of the slide so I'm forced to use a second column and cut it off at 6 items.
The 2 options I've come up with so far are:

Create 1 textbox and somehow split the list over 2 columns if necessary. This would fix the numbering issue as it's a single list, but I am not aware of any way to do this in slides (correct me if I missed something)

Create 2 textboxes and slice the data so the overflow is put into the second one instead. This works fine, but I'm stuck on the numbering problem here. I can create numbered lists just fine using the following code, but I can't find a way to make the numbering start from a different index.


  const textRange = box.getText();
  textRange.setText(''); // Clear data
  data.forEach((row) => {
    textRange.appendParagraph(row);
  })
  textRange.getListStyle().applyListPreset(SlidesApp.ListPreset.DIGIT_ALPHA_ROMAN);

Anyone here have an idea on how to solve these problems or a way to avoid them altogether?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your current issue and your expected result. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
